# The insured vs. the assured

Tags: differences, terminology

Consider the following statement (written in the context of marine cargo insurance):

> The *insurers* plead negligence on the part of the *assured*.

The writer is British.

Is the use of *assured* appropriate here? Or should it be *insured*?

The relevant definition of [*insure*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/insure) reads:

> arrange for compensation in the event of damage to or loss of (property), or injury to or the death of (someone), in exchange for regular payments to a company or to the state:

The corresponding entry for [*assure*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assure) reads:

> *chiefly British* cover (a life) by assurance:
>   we guarantee to assure your life

Does this mean that you can insure *anything* and assure only *a life*? What is the difference between *life insurance* and *life assurance*?

Comment: Seems to be that _life assurance_ is chiefly British English:  "Main Entry:life assurance  Function:noun  chiefly Britain : LIFE INSURANCE" (MW3UDE). So how it's said & written depends on where it's said & written and for whom it's said & written. That's different from _quality assurance_, which is universal (even the Klingons use it) English.

Comment: @BillFranke I've included some additional context.

Comment: Because I'm not a speaker of BrE, I can't say whether the sentences you're asking about are standard fare across the pond. They aren't standard American English. @Barrie England and Andrew Leach seem to me to be the guys who should actually answer this question, which is why I've offered only a comment.

Comment: Meaning #4 at [this entry](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/assurance) seems relevant. I'd interpret "especially" in that context to mean, "typically or usually, but not necessarily always".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly common to refer to insurance  as 'assurance', but, properly speaking, only *life insurance* is fit to be termed an *assurance*, while the other kinds of (non-life) insurances may be deemed to be *reassurances.*

The reason isn't far to seek.

A life insurance policy is the only one that is signed for *a sum assured* - 'assured', because all humans have to die some day. This ineluctable fact - that all humans are born to die - is the only *certainty* in insurance, whether or not multifarious other things come to pass.

So to answer your question, yes, you can insure (almost) *anything*, but can only be *assured* of someone collecting an insurance company payout in the case of a life insurance policy/plan, which is why it is also oftentimes called life *assurance*.

In other words, you might insure your house and possessions and nothing might ever be burgled. You can insure your car and drive without getting into a single accident for the rest of your life. You can insure against fire accidents and go without ever having to call the fireman in your waking life. But if you insure your life, you're insuring it for *a sum assured.* Hope this helps.

EDIT : Found and added [a link with a similar query](http://www.onlyinsurance.com/Life-Insurance/Why-is-it-called-life-assurance.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In English (BrE) assurance and assured can be used to mean insurance and insured.

Some financial and legal institutions in the UK, Canada, Australia and other territories which use British English, use these terms.

However in common usage and among many similar institutions the words insured, and insurance are more prevalent.

Most commonly it's seen in relation to Life Assurance, but it's application is not limited to this, it's generally considered somewhat archaic.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked in Marine Insurance for 39 years, including 12 years in the City as an Underwriter of the Institute of London Underwriters and I have been a lecturer of Marine Insurance at MIB Trieste (Italy) for the last 15 years, so perhaps you will allow me to try to be of some help.

"Assured" has always been used (with "insurance", "insurer" and "insured") in Marine Insurance, which is the origin of insurance (over 2,000 years; in its "modern form" only about 800 years) and now in Life Insurance/Assurance. For other branches "insurance" and "insured" are normally used in our market.

Marine underwriters like to call themselves "insurers" or "underwriters" and their clients "Assureds". As an example, here is a line from one of the Institute Cargo Clauses (A) (once called "all risks" and still one of the most used clauses in the world): "This insurance is extended to indemnify the Assured against such proportion of liability..."

Answer (score 1):

We perhaps need not only a speaker of British English to answer this, but perhaps one who is also a lawyer. However, my own experience broadly supports your conclusions about the use of these terms in the United Kingdom. *Assurance* provides payment to named beneficiaries in the event of death. *Insurance* is the financial protection of property against events such as fire, theft and flood.

Answer (score 1):

From a reading of available sources found by [searching for the quoted phrase](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=The+insurers+plead+negligence+on+the+part+of+the+assured.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#q=The+insurers+plead+negligence+on+the+part+of+the+assured.&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=weq&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&nirf=The+insurers+plead+negligence+on+the+part+of+the+insured.&ei=yaPqUJ_4JIyLkwW-w4HwBQ&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dGI&fp=fc7fe2b45ce62c75&bpcl=40096503&biw=1440&bih=796), it appears that in British maritime law a *risk* is insured by insurers and the person doing that insurance is called the *assured*.

A [House of Lords judgement,](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld200203/ldjudgmt/jd030220/hih-4.htm) which appears to be representative of the sources, contains the opinion of one of the Law Lords (my emphasis):

> 93: The relevant insurance contract contained a clause ... which ... specifically limited the **assured's** duty to disclose as is illustrated most clearly by section 6 of the clause (using the same sub-divisions as the judge and the Court of Appeal) - "the insured will not have any duty or obligation to make any representation, warranty or disclosure of any nature, express or implied (such duty and obligation being expressly waived by the insurers)".

Throughout the judgement, Their Lordships use the word *assured* for the person taking out the insurance policy, even though the contract uses *insured*.